# Why ImportError: cannot import name 'AutoReg' from 'statsmodels.tsa.ar_model' occuring?

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels, mle, vector-auto-regression

I am trying to do MLE regression using AR(p) by importing the module **from statsmodels.tsa.ar_model import AutoReg, ar_select_order**, but this ImportError keeps coming. How to solve this? Is there any other way I can do Autoregression in Python?

Answer (score 8):

AutoReg is a newer version of the previous AR model, it is only available in statsmodels with version >= 0.11.1. You may check your statsmodels version. If it is lower, you may do

```
pip install statsmodels --upgrade
```

Comment: I am still getting the error described in the post after upgrading. Do you have any other ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: After upgrading statsmodels package, restarting the Python environment I am working helped in my case.

Answer (score 2):

do `pip install statsmodels --upgrade` and restart the environment.